# Render only modified rows in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table which I am filling after sending an ajax request through jQuery. ajax request is made after every 10 seconds and it is returning a lot of data *(around 1000 rows - I know about pagination, but its not an option for me)*. Currently I am re-creating all the rows on each request. Is it possible that I can only modify the rows different from previous result set ?

My page is caching the current result set in an array and then with each subsequent request I am comparing the new result set with the previous and on change deleting the current html table and re-creating it. The process of rendering the new HTML table is taking a lot of time and I was wondering if there is a way to reduce that.

I have tried searching for it but couldn't find any thing related to it. I just need to know if it is possible with any jquery plugin ? or what strategy should I adopt for modifying changed rows and deleting rows that doesn't exist in the new dataset.

EDIT: Here is the current Code that I have

```
var sCurrentStr = "";
var sPreviousStr = "";
var bFirstRequest = true;
function OnGetListSuccess(sResponse)
{

    //build table from the response
    $(xmlDoc).find('Table').each(function ()
    {

        var sTitle = $(this).find('Title').text();
        var dBCDate = parseStringToLocalDate($(this).find('BCDateTime').text());
        var sDestination = $(this).find('DestinationName').text();

        //GetLocalDateFromUTCDate
        var dStartDate = parseStringToLocalDate($(this).find('StartDateTime').text());
        var dEndDate = parseStringToLocalDate($(this).find('EndDateTime').text());


        sCurrentStr += sTitle + dBCDate + sDestination + (dStartDate.toLocaleString()) + (dEndDate.toLocaleString());
    });

    if (bFirsRequest)
    {
        //cache results in sPreviousStr
        sPreviousStr = sCurrentStr;
        bFirstRequest = false;
    }

    if (sCurrentStr != sPreviousStr)
    {
        $(xmlDoc).find('Table').each(function ()
        {
                    $('<tr onclick="javascript:GetRowDetails(this)"></tr>').html('<td>' + '1' + '</td>' +

                        '<td style="width:0px;display:none" class="hiddenSearchClass">' + sCurrentStr + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + sTitle + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + dBCDate.toLocaleString() + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + sDestination + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + dStartDate.toLocaleString() + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + dEndDate.toLocaleString() + '</td>'
                        )
                    .appendTo('#MyHTMLTable');
        });
    }
    else
    {
     //no changes ignore it
     sPreviousStr = sCurrentStr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier for each row? Then you could compare each row separately instead of the whole result set.

Comment: Why don't you do the comparison on the server instead? That should be much faster.

Comment: @Thomas, I don't have it, but I am concatenating all the columns to form a single string and currently have that as a hidden field in my table.

Comment: @JeevanJose, I am fetching records from a table which is continuously getting modified from other services. I am getting that data through a web service. I am not sure how would I do the comparison in SQL since I can't store the result set in a temporary table.

Comment: Show us your current code, especially the part where you are comparing the ajax results with the stored set and the recreation of the table.

Comment: @Bergi, sure I will add that to my question.

Comment: Are the rows only modified on the server or also on your client?
If you want to find out if a row was modified on the server you need to have a unique identifier. Otherwise you can't differentiate between new rows and modified rows.

Comment: @NewHire I meant the web server where you have your 'logic'. Like  user1506980 said, you could 'mark' the rows that are modified in your web service and then access only those in your ajax callback.

Comment: @Bergi, just added the related code.

Comment: @NewHire like in my example/answer, I am utilizing "documentFragments" which stores dom elements to the memory. you can then collect __all__ the rows you want to add inside this fragment and append them all at once, that will considerably speed up your code. ie: remove the `.appendTo()` from the loop, and instead add each row to a `$()` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently are building a huge `currentString`, from which you then can only determine whether the whole table has changed (or not) (btw, you forgot to update `previousString` everytime you change something, you're only doing it after the first request).

Instead of that, you should store the single rows (xml `<Table>` elements) and a reference to the html row that would need updating.

```
var data = [];
function OnGetListSuccess(response) {
    //build table from the response
    var l = $(xmlDoc).find('Table').each(function(i) {
        var title = $(this).find('Title').text(),
            BCDate = parseStringToLocalDate($(this).find('BCDateTime').text()),
            destination = $(this).find('DestinationName').text(),
            startDate = parseStringToLocalDate($(this).find('StartDateTime').text()),
            endDate = parseStringToLocalDate($(this).find('EndDateTime').text());

        var prev = data[i];
        if (!prev // new element
          || prev.title!=title || +prev.BCDate!=+BCDate || prev.destination!=destination || +prev.startDate!=+startDate || +prev.endDate!=endDate) {
            data[i] = update(prev && prev.html, {
                title: title,
                BCDate: BCDate,
                destination: destination,
                endDate: endDate
            });
        }
    }).length;
    // remove deleted elements
    $.each(data.splice(l), function() {
       this.html.remove();
    });
}
function update(row, obj) {
    if (!row)
        obj.html = row = $("<tr>").click(function(e) {
            GetRowDetails(this); // can probably simplified by passing obj now
        }).appendTo('#MyHTMLTable');
    row.empty().html('<td>' + '1' + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + obj.title + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + obj.BCDate.toLocaleString() + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + obj.destination + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + obj.startDate.toLocaleString() + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + obj.endDate.toLocaleString() + '</td>'
                    );
    return obj;
}
```

This script doesn't deal best with deletions and insertions at arbitrary positions (to upgrade that you would use some kind of random-access-IDs), but you can see where this is going now.

Comment: Thank you Bergi for your response, I will try it now and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

If all the rows have a unique `id` coming back from the Ajax request you can add that as an attribute or class name initially on the `<tr>`'s and then delete/edit those `<tr>`'s as and when you notice that they have either been deleted in the newest rowset or edited.

You could also then add another class to the `<tr>` such as `updated` which when you've finished modding the table you can animate a background colour change which fades out on those `<tr>`'s and remove the 'updated' class at the same time.  That way the user can see which rows have changed - similar to a stock market price screen.

This can all be achieved quite simply with jQuery once you know which rows are needing to be updated/deleted and you have a reliable way or accessing those individual rows (via a unique identifier as mentioned above)  If you need any help with that please post an example of your HTML table and your returned Ajax data to a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely cannot get back the uid from the database, have you explored the option of "almost uniquely identifying" a row on ajax get?
eg:

```
 <tr id="column1_column2_column3_column4_column5_column6_...">...</tr>
```

where the `column1` etc is the result of this row's column
and then doing a function like below on the loop through the ajax response.

```
// create objects to store fragments
var $deleteThese = $();
var $addThese = $();

// run your ajax call, plus the loop through ajax response;

function loopThroughAjaxResponse( result ) {

  // store a dom reference to the "practically unique" row
  var $thisRow = $('#'+result.column1+'_'+result.column2+'_...');
  var $appendThis;

  // decide if the row already exists, if it does we 
  // append to the delete fragment
  if( $thisRow.length > 0 ) {
    $deleteThese = $deleteThese.add( $thisRow );
  }

  // and we append a newly created row to the append
  // fragment regardless.
  $appendThis = $('<tr id='+result.column1+'_'+result.column2+'_...>...</tr>');
  $addThese.append( $appendThis );

}

// then outside of the loop (importantly) we remove all
// the dom elements, and add them all at once.
$deleteThese.remove();
$addThese.appendTo( $('table') );
```

this is all theorycode, so you'll have to take the overall theory and apply it to your code since you didn't paste any example code :)

Comment: ah, you pasted code in the end :) but my theory still stands: create a "practically unique" identifier from the response columns, check if another row exists with that "practically unique" identifier and then create a collection for rows to add, and for rows to remove based on it. then add/delete all at once.